# Column <column name> does not belong to table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

I have created a table with 3 field in SQL. And added some data. Now  I want to insert more data into that table by coding.
If I click button_1 the data are to be inserted into table.
I tried by this given below code.

I have executed the given below query, but it shows an error: 
"Column 'Site Name' does not belong to table"
"Column 'SiteId' does not belong to table"
"Column 'Cluster' does not belong to table"

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strcon = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["insertBulkConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow rowAdded = dt.Rows.Add(); 
        rowAdded.SetField("SiteName", "A");
        rowAdded.SetField("State", "B");
        rowAdded.SetField("Cluster", "C");
    }
```

Comment: You have to open connection, write the query with required parameters, execute the query then it'll be inserted. Just google `insert data into sql using c#` and you will have thousands of useful links.

Comment: You should find a good tutorial on how to work with a database.

Answer (score 6):

The reason for the error is that you're trying to add a `DataRow` with three fields to a table that currently doesn't contain any `DataColumn`s. You have to use `dt.Columns.Add(...)` if you want to do that manually.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("SiteName", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("State", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Cluster", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add("A", "B", "C");
```

If the table was already filled and you want to add some rows manually(as mentioned in comment) you could use `SetField` to fill only some of the columns:

```
DataRow rowAdded =  dt.Rows.Add(); // already added at this point with empty fields
rowAdded.SetField("SiteName", "A");
rowAdded.SetField("State", "B");
rowAdded.SetField("Cluster", "C");
```

If you want to fill it from the database you can use `DataAdapter.Fill(table)`, f.e:

```
using(var con = new SqlConection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["insertBulkConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY Column", con))
{
    da.Fill(dt);  // you don't need to add the columns or to open the connection
}
```

Comment: Actually My table already contains some values, that i have entered manually in sql. Now i want to enter some data into that same table  by using one button click. So how can i insert values into that table?

Comment: @vipintp: what columns does the table contain? I have edited my answer to show how to modify only some of the columns.

Comment: Given below are the fields.
SiteName, State, Cluster

Comment: @vipintp: the columns do not belong to the table, the error message is very descriptive and i've also mentioned it in the answer. Its not clear what you're actually trying to do. _"My table already contains some value"_ what table are you referring to, to the `DataTable` or the table in the database. Don't confuse a `DataTable` with a db-table, it is just an in-memory collection similar to a list or array. You have to fill it in some way.

Comment: I have executed that code u given to me, but it shows another error is that column name does not belongs to that table.

Comment: @vipintp - when you do `new DataTable()`, it does *not* automatically get the columns from some unknown table that exists in sql. You need *some* way of telling that `DataTable` about those columns: fill it from the database or define the columns in code.

Comment: @Tim: Here I am referring to the Data table but actually I want to refer the database.
Is there any extra code for refer db. Actually I am beginner so I don't know how to do all these. Please help me.

Comment: @vipintp: Its still not clear what you're trying to do. I've provided three ways to fill or manipulate a `DataTable`. The last shows how to load a table from a database-table(in this example MS SQL-Server). Perhaps you should really read a tutorial first, then come back with a specific question. For example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171920.aspx